# Manual code deploys to Live, from SVN, through FTP

Tags: php, mysql, svn, deployment

I just inherited a new project. What surprises me is that all of the SVN code is being deployed manually with FTP, which is on average 50+ files per week. Each developer keeps a (rather long) list of each file they've changed.

In past projects, I've used tools such as an .sh script, or a tool like Springloops, or Phing. Anyone else manually deploy code to their SVN code to the live server with FTP?

Answer (score 0):

> Anyone else manually deploy code to their SVN code to the live server with FTP?

Yes, I do it (not by hand, in hook). Because CI-Deploy solutions are overkill *for my needs*

Comment: Do you move the files over one at a time by hand, or do you use a script to automate it?

Comment: @ApolloClark post-commit hook (for sftp) is automated - I'm **lazy** badger. But in some projects (small set and sporadic changes) I do it in interactive mode

Comment: Ok, I understand that. Basically, you're automating the file deploy after you SVN Commit, but not doing Unit Testing before that?

Comment: @ApolloClark - yes, no UT and CI at all: it's *not sources* in my case

Answer (score 0):

> SVN code to the live server

What happened to a staging / testing server? Code that's being checked in is rarely production-ready (you can't test your own code), so you don't want any checkin to be pushed to the live environment.

But any post-commit hook can copy the code to another location, that's quite a trivial task, like displayed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738499/svn-post-commit-hook-to-copy-committed-files-to-a-working-copy-for-another-repos).

Comment: CodeCaster - I agree entirely.I'm working for a new company, I'm slowly teaching them that Quality Control is important. For now, we do all of our testing manually on the Dev Server for a few hours or couple of days before a deploy. In the coming months I'm hoping to get the team doing Unit Tests, using Selenium, and doing Automated Deploys with Phing, per a Continuous Integration workflow.