# SVN (Subclipse) Commited files are not updated on server

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I'm a beginner with SVN.

Every time I commit a file in my project, the file is not created/updated on the server.

However, there is no errors when I commit and the SVN repo is updated.

When I check the last modified files on my server, the commited files are not created or updated but files concerning the SVN repo are updated (file created: /svn/myproject/db/revs/0/358).

How can my new file be on the server?

I use Eclipse with Subclipse for a PHP project. The server is on Ubuntu.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Read and undersand SVN Book
2. When you commit changes, they appear **only in repository**, which can not be used directly as source files  for site (site is **additional independent entity** as real files on filesystem of server)
3. It (site) can/must be updated in order to reflect latest changes **from repository** - this is manual work or task for post-commit hook
4. Because at least two ways exist for performing this job (`svn export` or updating Working Copy, which represent your site), you have to ask SVN-admin:

   - How it performed now
   - Why it does not work
5. If you haven't manual or post-commit task for updating, you have to write it

Comment: Thanks, I have created a **post-commit hook** using used this [script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3373775/1145134) and modified it to fit my need.