# SVN hook to modify files and sync after commit

Tags: svn, svn-hooks, post-commit

I'm looking for a way / post-commit hook to go through all committed files on every commit and remove some "known" confidential information from those files - like passwords with `sed`.
After this cleanup is done I would like to have those files commited into a seperate repository where another team can pick up the changes with just updating their repo.

Does someone have a handy shell script to achieve this ? Or provide me some documentation how to access the actual commited files and work them?

Thanks in advance

- mat1010

Comment: Maybe this direction can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446518/using-svn-post-commit-hook-to-update-only-files-that-have-been-commited Not exactly the same, but it seems to be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You can *reject* a commit using hook, but don't modify its contents. Let me cite [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.hooks):

> While hook scripts can do almost anything, there is one dimension in
>   which hook script authors should show restraint: do not modify a
>   commit transaction using hook scripts. While it might be tempting to
>   use hook scripts to automatically correct errors, shortcomings, or
>   policy violations present in the files being committed, doing so can
>   cause problems. Subversion keeps client-side caches of certain bits of
>   repository data, and if you change a commit transaction in this way,
>   those caches become indetectably stale. This inconsistency can lead to
>   surprising and unexpected behavior. Instead of modifying the
>   transaction, you should simply validate the transaction in the
>   pre-commit hook and reject the commit if it does not meet the desired
>   requirements. As a bonus, your users will learn the value of careful,
>   compliance-minded work habits.